# Leaving Microsoft Intune

Tags: microsoft, microsoft-intune, mdm

the last few months we tested device managment with Microsoft Intune. But for our workload we decided that Intune is not the right tool to use. So we don't extendes the trial period. We are currently managing 3 devices with Intune (and as the life plays this 3 devices are productive used). I'm looking for a way to migrate this devices back to normal Stand Alone devices without the need for reinstall. Does anyone have any idea how to do that?

Regards
Uwe

Comment: RTFM on how to unenroll a device?

Comment: Do you mean this link:
https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/intune-user-help/unenroll-your-device-from-intune-windows
I already read this page. But my questions still remains. Does this procedure deletes the whole user profile from the PC? How affects this Office licenses which are bind to the user accounts? Sadly we don't hae an test system where I could play this through.